# Prevent Magento to send email to a specific coustomer group

Tags: magento-1.9, email, customer-group

I need a way to prevent Magento sending any email to a specific user group.

For example I have a user group called "NoMail"

If a customer is created in that group i wold like Magento to NOT SEND any of the emails (creation, order, coment, credit memo, shipping).

Is there a file where i can set a contdition like

```
if UserGroup = (NoMail):
     break
 else if
    send email code......
```

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are unfortunately no events in the Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template and `Mage_Core_Model_Email classes`.

You have to extend the **Core Email Model**

1. Rewrite `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template`
2. only rewrite the `send()` function and put your condition there.

call parent `send()` function in extended function.

```
class Your_Module_Model_Core_Email_Template extends Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template {

public function send($email, $name = null, array $variables = array())
{
    //your logic
    /*if UserGroup = (NoMail):
       $return=false;
   else if 
       $return = parent::send($email, $name, $variables); */

   return $return;
}
```